# docker attach vs lxc-attach

Tags: linux, virtualization, docker, lxc

UPDATE: Docker 0.9.0 use libcontainer now, diverting from LXC see: [Attaching process to Docker libcontainer container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338509/attaching-process-to-docker-libcontainer-container)

I'm running an istance of elasticsearch:

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 dockerfile/elasticsearch
```

Checking the process it show like the following:

```
$ docker ps --no-trunc
CONTAINER ID                                                       IMAGE                             COMMAND                                           CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
49fdccefe4c8c72750d8155bbddad3acd8f573bf13926dcaab53c38672a62f22   dockerfile/elasticsearch:latest   /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch java   About an hour ago   Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   pensive_morse
```

Now, when I try to attach the running container, I get stacked:

```
$  sudo docker attach 49fdccefe4c8c72750d8155bbddad3acd8f573bf13926dcaab53c38672a62f22
[sudo] password for lsoave:
```

the tty doesn't connect and the prompt is not back. Doing the same with lxc-attach works fine:

```
$ sudo lxc-attach -n 49fdccefe4c8c72750d8155bbddad3acd8f573bf13926dcaab53c38672a62f22
root@49fdccefe4c8:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0 49 20:37 ?        00:00:20 /usr/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMa
root        88     0  0 20:38 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash
root        92    88  0 20:38 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
root@49fdccefe4c8:/#
```

Does anybody know what's wrong with docker attach ?

NB. [dockerfile/elasticsearch](https://index.docker.io/u/dockerfile/elasticsearch/) ends with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're attaching to a container that is running `elasticsearch` which isn't an interactive command. You don't get a shell to type in because the container is not running a shell. The reason `lxc-attach` works is because it's giving you a default shell. Per [man lxc-attach](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lxc-attach):

> If no command is specified, the current default shell of the user
>   running lxc-attach will be looked up inside the container and
>   executed. This will fail if no such user exists inside the container
>   or the container does not have a working nsswitch mechanism.

`docker attach` is behaving as expected.

Comment: expected but inconsistent IMHO

Answer (score 4):

As Ben Whaley notes this is expected behavior.
It's worth mentioning though that if you want to monitor the process you can do a number of things:

- Start bash as front process: e.g. `$ES_DIR/bin/elasticsearch && /bin/bash` will give you your shell when you attach. Mainly useful during development. Not so clean :)
- Install an ssh server. Although I've never done this myself it's a good option. Drawback is of course overhead, and maybe a security angle. Do you really want ssh on all of your containers? Personally, I like to keep them as small as possible with single-process as the ultimate win.
- Use the log files! You can use `docker cp` to get the logs locally, or better the `docker logs $CONTAINER_ID` command. The latter give you the accumulated stdin/stderr output for the entre lifetime of the container each time though.
- Mount the log directory. Just mount a directory on your host and have elasticsearch write to a logfile in that directory. You can have syslog on your host, Logstash, or whatever turns you on ;). Of course, the drawback here is that you are now using your host more than you might like. I also found a nice experiment using logstash [in this blog](http://denibertovic.com/post/docker-and-logstash-smarter-log-management-for-your-containers/).

Comment: Current attempts at using /bin/bash as a front process and attaching after are failing. The container is automatically shut down (so /bin/bash is not remaining running as a front process).

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, now that Docker 1.3 is released, you can use "docker exec" to open up a shell or other process on a running container. This should allow you to effectively replace lxc-attach when using the native driver.

http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/