# Attaching process to Docker libcontainer container

Tags: docker

In Docker releases previous to v0.9.0, you could attach(inject) a process into a container by using lxc-attach. For example:

```
docker run -d ubuntu:12.04
docker inspect {{containerhash}} | grep ID
// "ID": "d846ae242838de66f12414fbc8807acb3c77778bdb81babab7115261f4242284"
sudo lxc-attach -n d846ae242838de66f12414fbc8807acb3c77778bdb81babab7115261f4242284 -- /bin/bash
```

This no longer works because of the 0.9.0 switch to libcontainer.

How can we do this via libcontainer?

There is an option to switch to lxc with a startup option, but I'd like to know how this can be accomplished via libcontainer.

Comment: Look at all my answer on the subject. I always recommend against lxc-attach because of this :). However, it is still possible with nsinit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check if you have the `nsenter` tool. It should be in the `util-linux` package, after version 2.23. Note: unfortunately, Debian and Ubuntu still ship with util-linux 2.20.

If you have `nsenter`, it's relatively easy. First, find the PID of the first process of the container (actually, any PID will do, but this is just easier and safer):

```
PID=$(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' my_container_id)
```

Then, enter like this:

```
nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```

Voilà! Note, however, that `nsenter` won't honor capabilities.

If you don't have `nsenter` (e.g. if you are using Debian or Ubuntu, or your distro has too old util-linux), you can download util-linux and compile it. I have a `nsenter` binary, maybe I can upload it to the Docker registry if that could help anyone.

Another option is to use `nsinit`, a helper tool for libcontainer. I don't think that there is a lot of documentation for `nsinit` since it's very new, but check https://asciinema.org/a/8090 for an example. You will need a Go build environment.