# Docker Change Port Binding

Tags: port, docker

I'm running a container (let's call it `old_container`) with `exposed` port 80 and bind the port to the host interface on port 80 using  the `-p` flag.

> sudo docker run -p 80:80 -i -t < old-image-id >

In my production environment I want to switch now from the `old_container` to a `new_container`. So I want to shut down the `old_container` and start the `new_container`.

First I have to do some manual changes in the `new_container`. So I run it without the `-p` flag, as I cannot bind it to port 80 before I have done this changes.

```
sudo docker run -i -t < new-image-id >
#now I m doing my manual changes
```

When I'm finished with my changes I logout of the `new_container`. My plan was now to stop the `old_container` and bind the `new_container` to port 80. But the `[start][1]` command does not provide a port binding possibility.

So to come to my question: I'm looking to set the port binding for a stopped container, preferably without the workaround of creating a commit image of the `new_container` and running this image as another new container.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container?rq=1)

Comment: Do not like the answer :) Leave the question open. Probably there will be a way in the future to do this

Answer (score 7):

1. Make the changes to your new container and then **stop** both the old and new containers.

```
docker stop old_container new_container
```

2. Create a new image from a container’s changes via the **commit** command like so:

```
docker commit new_container new_container_01
```

3. **Run** the newly commited image:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -i -t new_container_01
```

4. Cleanup your old, unused containers with the **rm** *(remove)* command:

```
docker rm old_container new_container
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds good, its quite interesting to see docker on PROD. What is the manual change you are going to do? Although, I assume the solution to your problem might be

1) Attaching & detaching a container ([How do I attach to a running Docker container later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752581/how-to-keep-a-docker-container-running?answertab=votes#tab-top))

`docker attach container_name
ctrl p ctrl q`

2) Running docker exec command

`docker run -it -p 80:80 --name=old_container <old-image-id>`

The above command will create a container named "old_container"

`docker exec -d <old_container> mkdir foo`

The above command will create foo directory on home folder of running container. I guess you can include your manual changes as a script in place of 'mkdir foo'(I never tried it)

**P.S**: docker exec is available only from docker 1.3 version

Answer (score 0):

I did create a tools for [change PORT of Running Container](https://github.com/wharsojo/myboot2docker#change-port-of-running-container) for [myboot2docker](https://github.com/wharsojo/myboot2docker).

Ex: two(2) container:

- docker run -p 11521:1521 --name=xe1 container1
- docker run -p 21521:1521 --name=xe3 container3

I create another port-mapping for container1 using this command

```
p-map xe1 15210:1521
```

and then I connect my Spring Java application to localhost:15210

to switch to container3 just type this command

```
p-map xe3 15210:1521
```

below are details command in action.

```
~ $ p-map
Change port of running container
Command: p-map <container_name> <host_port:guest_port>

DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:21521 to:172.17.0.1:1521
DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:11521 to:172.17.0.2:1521

~ $ p-map xe1 15210:1521
Change port of running container

sudo iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport 15210 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.1:1521

DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:21521 to:172.17.0.1:1521
DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:11521 to:172.17.0.2:1521
DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:15210 to:172.17.0.1:1521 --

~ $ p-map xe2 15210:1521
Change port of running container
Error: No such image or container: xe2

DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:21521 to:172.17.0.1:1521
DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:11521 to:172.17.0.2:1521
DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:15210 to:172.17.0.1:1521 --

~ $ p-map xe3 15210:1521
Change port of running container

sudo iptables -t nat -D DOCKER -p tcp --dport 15210 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.1:1521
sudo iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport 15210 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:1521

DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:21521 to:172.17.0.1:1521
DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:11521 to:172.17.0.2:1521
DNAT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:15210 to:172.17.0.2:1521 --
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you run your new_container image and make the changes you require, save the new container as a new image using `docker commit`. then run this new image with -p flag to map the ports.